# How can I use the PyCharm debugger with Google Cloud permissions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I have a simple flask app that talks to Google Cloud Storage.

When I run it normally with `python -m api.py` it inherits Google Cloud access from my cli tools.

However, when I run it with the PyCharm debugger it can no longer access any Google Services.

I've been trying to find a way to have the PyCharm debugger inherit the permissions of my usual shell but I'm not seeing any way to do that.

Any tips on how I can use the PyCharm debugger with apps that require access to Google Cloud?

Comment: I usually download the credentials file and set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"` environment variable in PyCharm.

Comment: @Asdfg it seems that is only for service accounts. Is it best practice to user service accounts for this? Do you know if there is a way to  make a  credentials file representing my whole account?

Comment: I don't know if it is a best practice or not but it gives me an opportunity to limit what my program can do. So if I write something that may have disrupting effect, I don't have to worry about it. Works great for me. I later use the same service account and attach it to the `cloud function` and it works out just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Would you like to write your common as an answer so I can mark as solved or I can write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually download the credentials file and set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json` environment variable in PyCharm.

I usually create a directory called `auth` and place the credential file there and add that directory to `.gitignore`

I don't know if it is a best practice or not but it gives me an opportunity to limit what my program can do. So if I write something that may have disrupting effect, I don't have to worry about it. Works great for me. I later use the same service account and attach it to the `Cloud Function` and it works out just fine for me.